# Method has no supported translation to SQL(Linq to Sql)

Tags: linq-to-sql

After I execute a query on the database, and try to print the result of that execution, I got this error:

> Method has no supported translation to SQL.

My code:

```
Table<User> users = DAL.DALConnection.Database.GetTable<User>();

var query = from user in users
            where user.Get_UserName().ToString() == username
            select user;

foreach (User user in query)
     Console.WriteLine(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `Get_UserName()` a C# function you've written in your code?  If so, the error coming back makes sense, because SQL Server doesn't know about that function.

Instead, you would probably want to do something like `where user.username == username`, assuming your table has a `username` field.

Comment: i tried to change username to public to access like where `user.username == username`, but the problem is when i create a `[Column(Name="UserName",Storage="username")]` then username must be a private variable.